# Для чего нужны сервисы на ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

При создании приложения сделал сервис для получения и обработки данных:

import Ember from 'ember';
import HttpService  from "../../http/http_service";

```
export default HttpService.extend({
    config: Ember.inject.service('admin.config'),

    fetch (data) {
        var config = this.get('config');
        return this.getData(config.urls.sOrders, data, {} );
    }
});
```

В контроллере:

```
this.get('service').fetch(data).subscribe(
res => {
 self.set('model.result', res);
}
```

На данном этапе всё работает. Но хотелось не получать данные каждый раз аяксом, а чтобы данные где-то хранились.

Прочитал, что есть store в ember, и хотел уточнить: как можно из сервиса записать данные в store? 
И будут ли они храниться на протяжении жизни приложения?

Comment: модель как сделана?

Comment: через Ember.Object.extend. в роуте  `return App.AddOrderModel.create({})`